# Flutter native view: startActivity Failed to resolve attribute at index 6

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm implementing Flutter plugin for a 3rd party library which uses native view to display Android Views in flutter. The library has a set of predefined views which start an Activity after click - the click is handled by the Android native code which invokes startActivity.

The error I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:596)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3967)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1027)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:968)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:100)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:194)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
```

After going through a lot of similar issues, the most probable cause of this error is missing definition of colorAccent or other value.

I managed to debug the app and determined that the index 6 corresponds to the `com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColorLink`
here's the complete snippet from TextView.java:

```
    private void readTextAppearance(Context context, TypedArray appearance,
        TextAppearanceAttributes attributes, boolean styleArray) {
    final int n = appearance.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        final int attr = appearance.getIndex(i);
        int index = attr;
        // Translate style array index ids to TextAppearance ids.
        if (styleArray) {
            index = sAppearanceValues.get(attr, -1);
            if (index == -1) {
                // This value is not part of a Text Appearance and should be ignored.
                continue;
            }
        }
        switch (index) {
            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColorHighlight:
                attributes.mTextColorHighlight =
                        appearance.getColor(attr, attributes.mTextColorHighlight);
                break;
            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColor:
                attributes.mTextColor = appearance.getColorStateList(attr);
                break;
            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColorHint:
                attributes.mTextColorHint = appearance.getColorStateList(attr);
                break;
            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColorLink:
          --->      attributes.mTextColorLink = appearance.getColorStateList(attr);
                break;
            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textSize:
                attributes.mTextSize =
                        appearance.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, attributes.mTextSize);
                attributes.mTextSizeUnit = appearance.peekValue(attr).getComplexUnit();
                break;
```

I tried adding the following properties both to the application styles and the styles used to inflate the platform view:

```
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#d3b170</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#d3b170</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#d3b170</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#d3b170</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#d3b170</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#d3b170</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#d3b170</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#d3b170</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline">
    <item name="android:textColor">#d3b170</item>
</style>
```

The platform view itself is created in the following way:

```
internal class CustomNativeView(context: Context, id: Int, creationParams: Map<String?, Any?>?) :
PlatformView {
private val view: NativeView

override fun getView(): View {
    return view
}

override fun dispose() {}

init {
    view = NativeView(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MainTheme), null)
}}
```

To summarise:
`CustomNativeView` is a platform view displayed inside `AndroidView`, this view starts an activity after click (on the native side) which cannot be inflated due to the error described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the library source code, I noticed that the newly created Activity has a custom theme set in onCreate(). Overwriting this style in the plugin's style.xml solved the issue:

```
<style name="Theme.SomePlugin.XYZ.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#000000</item>
</style>
```